# Why does this 2Pi-Periodic function looks like this?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, pi

I am given this function [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n8oj.png) on an interval $[0,\pi]$ and am asked to make a sketch of it on an interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. When plugging it into Maple, I am given a sketch graph like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djypt.png), however, that is incorrect. According to the solutions by my professor, the graph is supposed to look like this [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIvQe.png). I particularly don't understand the left side of the graph, why is it just like the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem specifies it is an even function. That is, $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Could you please clarify? I still don't quite understand that? Does it mean the function turns into 1+t?

Comment: @Velionis In the region $-1 < t < 0$, yes.

Comment: Alright, but this is not given in the equation? what is the entire function then? How could I plot the whole function in Maple then?

Comment: You are given the function in the interval $[0,\pi]$. You are told it is even ($f(-t) = f(t)$) and has period $2\pi$ ($f(t + 2\pi) = f(t)$). Since every real number $t$ can be expressed as $2\pi n \pm x$ for some integer $n$ and $x \in [0,\pi]$, you have enough information to find the value of the function at every real number.